# Angular 8 site not loading on iOS (iPhone and iPad) browsers, but loads on all other tested devices

Tags: ios, angular

I have an Angular 8 app that has a static HTML loading spinner and a chat overlay embed that shows during the load. However, the loading spinner never goes away. I don't have a lot to go on since I can't get dev tools on my iPad or iPhone. I did use `chrome://inspect` but the only log was a third-party embed `INFO` log.

EDIT: I am using Sentry, but my error service isn't catching anything to send to it.

I've read a few articles mentioning bootstrapping failures on certain devices, but they were all due to one node module or another.

Comment: why don't you try setting up some error logging to a server? You could use something like Sentry, or all I do is have an error service that intercepts all unhandled errors and sends their details to a database.

Comment: I have Sentry and an error service, neither of which are logging any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [article](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8546#issuecomment-345485725) this morning that mentions different build options negatively affecting iOS browsers. I started with `--no-sourcemap` and `--sourcemap`. Eventually, I got a full render.